# Intento descargar módulos con pip y me sale el siguiente error: [WinError 10013]

Tags: python, cmd, pip

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D52BA49710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Intento de acceso a un socket no permitido por sus permisos de acceso')': /simple/panda/

Comment: Parece un problema de permisos de acceso a la red. ¿Tienes un cortafuegos que te lo está impidiendo? ¿O una directiva de empresa que fuerza a pasar por un proxy?

Comment: Desactivo el cortafuegos y el antivirus y sigue igual. Es mi laptop personal

Answer (score 0):

acabo de tener este problema y conecte a otra red wifi y se soluciono el problema. Al parecer el problema esta en la compañía de internet que restringe la descarga.
prueba a darle internet a tu laptop desde conexión compartida por el móvil
así acabo de solucionarlo. Espero te sirva